# Diet problem and the Simplex Method - Should I normalize or scale values?

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, linear-programming, nonlinear-optimization

I'm working with the two-phase simplex method to constrain a large set of foods to a min and max range of nutrients. So say for calories, I'm selecting foods and quantity of that food to fit the boundaries between 2000 and 2300.

I've got this working pretty well, but I've noticed that when I play around with unit types (switching between milligrams or grams) I get some odd behavior that makes the program more or less robust. Meaning, it finds the solution more consistently when the unit is set a certain way. It seems like this shouldn't matter since they both represent the same quantity. Say for sodium, if I use 2.3 grams for the upper range as apposed 2300 mg, it comes up with a close to optimal solution more often than if I use 2300 mg. This is also the case for other nutrients as well and the units vary from ug to mg and g. So my question is, since one nutrients upper range might be in the single or double digits, and another in the triple or quadruple, could this be making the optimization process more difficult for the program to compute?

I've read some material that suggests a pre-process to scale or maybe normalize all of the values before running the simplex method to get all the values in more of a similar range, is this a common procedure and something I should be implementing? I'm also thinking that maybe the floating point resolution on the nutrient values is making a difference. So if a value of 45678.25 in mg, gets converted to grams that number is now 45.67825, would the extra resolution in the decimal places make a difference? I'm fairly new to optimization problems and just a little lost on this! Thanks for any help.

Comment: Are you saying that sometimes you do not get the optimal solution? Do you get a solution at all in those cases, or a suboptimal solution? Do you use existing software, or did you make your own implementation of dual simplex?

Comment: I don´t think that it makes a difference if the units are in mg or in g. But the units should be all in the same unit of measurement.

Comment: Thanks for the comments! To LinAlg, currently I'm using my own implementation. Since I'm trying to hit the min/max values to about 33 different nutrient vals, it never quite gets them all in the min/max range, a perfect optimal solution, but its gets very close and about 90-95% of them are in the target ranges. For the nutrients that it doesn't get in the min/max value range, its usually close enough and not off by much. I'm going re-word my question though since it does say optimal solution, which is incorrect!

Comment: I ran out of space! To give more context, my program picks a few hundred foods then parses this list down to anywhere from 5-10 foods. I would say about 70-80% of the time it comes up with a solution that is very close to optimal, and then it can really drop the ball and not even come close. But this is where my question comes into play, depending on the units chosen, the consistency of a close to optimal solution can drop off to about 50-60% when different units are chosen.

Comment: Thanks Callculus! I think I'm going to try converting everything to the same unit of measurement and see how it goes.

Comment: @PaulCampbell Good idea.